# Wix: ListBox value limitation

Tags: listbox, wix, windows-installer

Value field in ListBox table has String[64] type. Is there posible to expand this 64-characters limitation? I need to store some directory pathes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably (never tried) possible in WiX to override the default schema of he ListBox table. I know in InstallShield I just go to the direct editor and adjust it.  WiX has a template schema that is used to build the MSI and you might be able to use the Table element to redefine it.  Or it might just give you an error message saying you are defining a well known table.

However, I'm not sure if there would be any side effects in the ListBox control if you exceed 64 char.  I don't see anything in the MSI SDK saying what's allowed so I guess your milage may vary.

Here's a trick that you might like though.  It's called the evil twin dialog trick.  See, in MSI there's a bug that UI elements don't refresh very well and this trick works around it.  Consider this:

Dialog1  with ListBox associated to property TESTPROP and Items One value 1 and Two value 2.
Textlabel that displayes [TESTPROP].

When start the dialog the text label is empty after clicking a row in the listbox.  Click back and next and suddenly it has the expected text of 1 and 2.

Now create a clone of this dialog ( Dialog2 ) and put a control event on the Listbox of dialog1 that says NewDialog Dialog2 condition=1  and put a control event on the Listbox of dialog2 that says NewDialog Dialog1 condition = 1

Now when you run it the screen refreshes ( although with a big of an ugly flicker )   See it looks like it's the same dialog only it's really the evil twin dialog that's being transitioned to so that the data refreshes correctly.

Now for extra credit use your custom actions to do something like this

ListBox Item 1  Text C:\Pro...Foo\Bob  value LISTBOXDIRPROP1
ListBox Item 2  Text C:\Pro...Foo\Ed  value LISTBOXDIRPROP2

Property LISTBOXDIRPROP1 = C:\Program Files\Foo\Bob
Property LISTBOXDIRPROP2 = C:\Program Files\Foo\Ed

Then set your TextLabel to display [[TESTPROP]].  This tells it to get deference the value of the value of the property.  In other words,  TESTPRO = LISTBOXDIRPROP1 = C:\Proggram Files\Foo\Bob

This trick would allow you to display a line that fits the 64 char constraint yet gives additional information when the user selects it.

Comment: Thanks. I already know about controls refresh problem and twin dialogs solution and use it.

Comment: Solution with CustomTable didn't work. Wis just ignores my custom ListBox table and creates default ListBox table with String[64] Value type.

Comment: Try editing the schema with Orca after you build the MSI and see how it behaves.  I suspect 64 is the limit and you'll have to do the textlabel trick that I mention.

Comment: I can adjust ListBox table in Orca and set there 255 max characters, but I cant find solution how do this from Wix.

Comment: If you adjust it to 255, does the ListBox control display data correctly?  If so, you could write a postbuild script to programatically alter the table each time the MSI is built.

Comment: Another possibility is that I'm pretty sure that WiX uses a template schema to model it's database off of and that you could modify this schema so that MSI's built are already 255.  Unfortunatly I'm having a hard time proving this memory ( can't find the file ) and it would also create a magical build machine antipattern.  I suggest postbuild script instead.

Comment: Nope. I can't add value to "updated" ListBox table because ValidateNew throws me StringOverflow error. :(

Comment: I think you aren't going to win this one with MSI.  You are going to have to tweak your UI to show an abbreviated text in the listbox and full text in a details view ( text label ) or switch to a completly different pattern.  It just is what it is.

Comment: Will try to store actual values into some property and show user short text. I need store those values to use them in my WriteConfiguration deffered CA.